# What is the max connection limit of ajax long poll?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, comet, long-polling

For how many second can I keep a connection open? I mean, how long will the browser wait for an answer before a timeout and connect again to the longpoll.php?

Answer (score 0):

That depends very much on what browser you are using (Ranging from a couple of seconds to an hour and beyond). Theoretically it is only limited by the 8 hour TCP Timeout.

Comment: You'll have to ask facebook. I have no idea why or even if they do that.

Comment: Usually you don't - they have better things to do that explaining their technical decisions (if it even was one). As mentioned before that time limit is more likely to be a result of your browsers settings than an active design decision of facebook's dev-team.

Comment: In the same browser I tested it I created 3 minute connection (it is not only long poll but a little bit same)and Then I saw that facebook connection is 51 second.Then I tested them from different browsers and different computers and they are also same like my browser.

Comment: Then they seem to limit their timeout in javascript. In jQuery for example you would do it like this: `$.ajax({url: "longpoll.php",error: function(){},success: function(){},timeout: 51000});`

Comment: Not actually I use xhr long polling and comet and some special codes.They also have done something like this.They use xhr polling and comet to achieve this.